# Retrieving Facebook check ins using iOS graph API - no data

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use Facebook's Graph API to retrieve a list of checkins for myself from an iPhone application. I've requested a token and am able to access my profile information and a list of my friends, but when I request checkins I always get back an empty record set. I'm guessing it has something to do with the permissions I'm requesting, but I can do the query with the same permission on the Facebook Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fcheckins) and I do get data.

Token request:

```
NSArray *perm = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
    @"user_status", @"user_events", @"user_location",
    @"friends_checkins", @"friends_status", nil];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:perm
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session,
   FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
     //handle the session opening
 }];
```

Then when I try to retrieve the checkins (in seperate view controller):

```
[[FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"/me/checkins"] startWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
   NSDictionary<FBGraphObject> *checkins,
   NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
         NSLog(FBSession.activeSession.description);
         NSArray *data = [checkins objectForKey:@"data"];
         for (FBGraphObject *c in data) {
             //execution never gets here because data is empty
         }
     }
 }];
```

The execution never reaches the `for` loop because the `data` variable is empty.

I've printed out the current session state just before the `for` loop to ensure that everything is correct. the result was:

```
<FBSession: 0x15555555, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0x5555555, appID: 
55555555555, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 
0x15555555>, expirationDate: 4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, refreshDate: 2013-05-15 06:55:56 
+0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
    "user_status",
    "user_events",
    "user_location",
    "friends_checkins",
    "friends_status"
)>
```

I can't figure out what I might be missing.

Comment: Have you tried to print current session state and error! If you're not reaching to `for` loop block then it may chance of error there!

Comment: The `error` is `nil` (execution gets to the `for` loop, but not into it). I've added the print out of session description to the question. Thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: yese you need to get `user_checkins` and `friends_checkins` for Own Checkin List and Friends Checking list respectively, for more details visit [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/)

Comment: That's it - thanks. Add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as answered.